# How to combine different node in single views

Tags: views, nodes, flags

I'm currently doing recruitment system by using drupal 7..

First..
In my system, applicant need to fill up the "Applicant Profile" (node) before they can apply for the job.

Second..
i am using flag module..if applicant want to apply the job, they must flag the job..after that, they need to fill up their "name" and make some "pitch" (Flagging form)..

Third..
In my views, i add "flag" at relationship so i can add the flagging form details in the fields.At filter criteria, i add the "content:type (Applicant Profile)"

**My question..**
how i want to combine the details in **flagging form** and **applicant profile** in single views?
because currently the views fields only can display the flagging form details..

i already add two different "content:type" at filter criteria. but it does't work..it only show the details on one content type only.. 

Thank You in advance..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For `Applicant Profile` use [Profile 2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) module instead of node. Then when you create the `View` of `Job List`, add relation to `Flags`, `Content: Author` and `User:Profile`, in that way you will get all the fields you need.

Answer (score 0):

Click the Filter for Content Type and checkbox the other content type you need.

Comment: i already done that..but still cannot..because the details is from flagging form. i want to get the applicant profile details. the nid for this views is referring to the job that applicant flag..

Comment: try an or filter group and add has field